# Fetch corresponding row value on match column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns and one row, and need to get the column headers for every time that a specific value appears. For example:

```
Date               c1    col2    col3    col4    col5    rl6    d7 
01/01/2016 00:00   37.04   36.57   35.77   37.56   36.79   35.90   38.15
```

... and given an array with the column names `['col2','col3','col4','col5']`,

I need to compare these names with header names, and wherever the column name matches the array, then get the corresponding value in a row. For example, `col2` should give value `36.57`

Comment: This is just a straight lookup with `df.loc[:, list_of_col_names].values`. What output do you want: a pandas Series, a list, a numpy array...? Appending `.values` transforms from a DataFrame to a numpy array.

Comment: Thats right. I did the same thing. After the posting the question,I come up with this idea

Comment: anmol you stated things backwards: you don't want to to *get the column headers for every time that a specific value appears*; you want to *get the array of values given an input list of column names*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Make a Series containing the columns you want to retrieve
s = pd.Series(['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])

# Get the list of valid column names
# Notice that you don't have a `col1` column in your sample input
valid = s[s.isin(df.columns)]

df[valid]
```

Result

```
    col2   col3   col4    col5
0  36.57  35.77  37.56  36z.79
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your data frame is

> df

and you have the array,

```
l = ['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
```

Then you will get the corresponding values of labels by,

```
[df[label].values[0] for label in l if label in df]
```

Output of your example will be

```
[36.57, 35.77, 37.56, 36.79]
```

hope it helps you.